# Ruby update all same object data in hash array for JSON.parse

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So `a = first` is

```
=> <Ng::EntityConfiguration id: 15903, entity_id: 1, entity_type: "Ng::Company", key: "wpa2.psk", value: "[{"ssid":"Main-Hall-Staff","password":"abc123","dhcp":"Enabled"},{"ssid":"Main-Hall-Guest","password":"def456","dhcp":"Disabled"}]", created_at: "2016-11-08 11:03:51", updated_at: "2016-11-08 11:03:51", name: "WIFI/Main Hall">
```

I have `a.value` which is will return:

```
"[
  {\"ssid\":\"Main-Hall-Staff\",\"password\":\"abc123\"},
  {\"ssid\":\"Main-Hall-Guest\",\"password\":\"def456\"}
]"
```

My question is, how to update both password value and save it?

```
new_pass1 = 'xyz123'
new_pass2 = 'xyz321'
```

I have tried code (below) but this will only update first password if i only have one hash_array.

Here is my full code

```
def encrypt_pass
  # get the actual password
  parse = JSON.parse(self.value)
  get_pass = parse.last['password']

  # encrypt the password
  crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"])
  encrypted = crypt.encrypt_and_sign(get_pass)

  # save the new encrypted password
  parse.first['password'] = encrypted
  encrypt_pass = parse.to_json
  self.value = encrypt_pass
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, you're trying to update both the Main-Hall-Staff password and the Main-Hall-Guest password (all passwords) from your record to be the encrypted version of themselves? I'm assuming this method is called in a before_save callback of some sort? If you show more code related to the model I can give you more details.

```
def encrypt_pass
  # Changed the name to devises, always use easy to understand naming
  # Also rescuing from a JSON parse error, this isnt always recommended
  # as it hides other errors that might be unrelated to parsing
  devices = JSON.parse(self.value) rescue []
  crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"])

  devices.each do |device|
    # get the actual password
    password = device['password']

    # encrypt the password
    encrypted_pass = crypt.encrypt_and_sign(password)

    # Save the encrypted password
    device['password'] = encrypted_pass
  end

  self.value = devices.to_json
end
```

Hopefully you have some logic surrounding when this method is called as you dont want to encrypt an already encrypted password.

Comment: You are right.. this method is called before_save callback. Thanks alot Tyler. your code working great..